# Achieve Rhombus button with ShapeAppearance, not Drawable

Tags: android, android-button

I'm creating our button style in xml.  For this button, we need angled sides. I am able to get an EXTREME angle using ShapeAppearance but I need to soften that up.

Is it possible to do this without a drawable?

What I'm trying to do:

[image]

What I have now:

[image]

How I got this far:

```
<style name="MyApp.ShapeAppearance.Cut" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">0%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">100%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">100%</item>
</style>
```